# Time Varying Difference in Differences Model

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, methodology, economics, treatment

If I am looking at the impact of different tariffs in different months on exports, [image]

can anyone tell me if this would be the correct difference in differences model?
[image]

Or would it be [image]

[image]

Comment: It seems you have continuous treatment and multiple time periods. You better read papers dealing with continues treatment.

Comment: Welcome. What is your treatment? Is it the tariff value?

Comment: @ThomasBilach The treatment is the tariff value on tariff targeted products and non-tariff targeted products

Comment: Do you want to model treatment continuously? I see you have both the tariff value *and* a dichotomous variable for treatment.

Comment: I want to model tariffs that were implemented in different months on the products, I am very unsure how to do this @ThomasBilach

Comment: It sounds like you want to see how the treatment varies with the time since first exposure. Am I correct? Is the treatment growing or fading out over the months?